# filter pandas dataframe on column and add string to the filtered data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am having a dataframe column that contains either 4 or 6 char strings in length, I would like to add "00" string to the end of the strings having length of 4.

I am using this code but its giving me a syntax error.

```
df['col'] = np.where((df['col'].str.len() = 4, df['col'].astype(str) +'00' , df['col']'])
```

Comment: `df['col'].str.len() == 4` (you forgot one `=` sign)

Answer (score 3):

The clean *pandas* way to do this is to use [ljust](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.ljust.html) instead:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['col'] = pd.Series(['aaaa', 'bbbbbb'], dtype='string')

df['col'] = df['col'].str.ljust(6, '0')
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
      col
0  aaaa00
1  bbbbbb
```

From the documentation above:

> Return the string left justified in a string of length width. Padding
> is done using the specified fillchar (default is an ASCII space). The
> original string is returned if width is less than or equal to len(s).

*pandas* offers a rich api to work with text, see [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html) for more information.